# iOS 5 not autorotating view when loadView is called the second time

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, ios5, rotation

When I run my app in landscape mode, the second time my view controller's view is loaded and `loadView` is called, iOS 5 is not rotating the root view controller's view away from portrait, nor is it calling the view controller's willRotate / willAnimateRotation / didRotate methods.

As mentioned, this happens only after the view is unloaded and `loadView` is called the second time. In my app, I sometimes unload a view controller's view programmatically before I set it as the root view controller. However, this also happens when the view controller's view is unloaded automatically due to a low memory warning.

This only happens on iOS 5, not iOS 4.x. It's easy to reproduce in iOS simulator, and here is a link to a stand-alone test app that reproduces this problem:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/7ob5xw5ym02pasx/ViewControllerTest.zip

To see the issue, just compile the app and start it in landscape mode with iOS 5.0 Simulator, then tap "A" and then "Back", and you'll see how the rotation doesn't occur.

Any ideas? Does this have to do with how I'm setting `window.rootViewController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I debugged through it and there seems to be a change between 4.3 and 5.0. In 4.3 UIKit calls `[UIWindow addRootViewController:]`, in 5.0 it calls `[UIWindow setRootViewController:]`. So maybe something changed that we can't see...

I'd suggest working around this, by **not** using `[newController setupStuff]` (thus **not** setting the view to nil), but rather overriding

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // do setup stuff here, reset content etc etc.
}
```

and resetting the (already loaded) view, before it actually appears on screen.

Additional info:

a) you don't need to set the view to nil. The system does that for you. When you access the view property of that view controller the next time, the system calls `loadView` to recreate the view:

> If you access this property and its value is currently nil, the view
>   controller automatically calls the loadView method and returns the
>   resulting view. The default loadView method attempts to load the view
>   from the nib file associated with the view controller (if any).

b) It all boils down to behavior in iOS 5 regarding the window's `rootViewController` property. In iOS 5 these two are **not** equivalent:

```
 self.window.rootViewController = newController;
```

vs

```
 [self.window.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
 [self.window addSubview:newController.view];
```

The former completely ignores orientation, the latter doesn't.

To make things even more complicated, if one does **not override** `loadView`, but instead lets the system auto-create an empty UIView and only modifies that view in `viewDidLoad`, a memory warning won't automatically set the view to nil and release it - docs:

> ```
> The default implementation releases the view only if it determines that it is safe to do so.
> ```

Magic. Depending if one overrides the method or not. I can't really test this in any way.

Case 1 - overridden `loadView`:
Triggering the memory warning calls both`didReceiveMemoryWarning` and `viewDidUnload`

Case 2 - no `loadView`:
Triggering the memory warning in simulator **only** calls `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, but not `viewDidUnload`

I'd say, add the view manually...

cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- but unfortunately that won't work in the case when the view is set to nil by the system (view controller responding to a low memory warning).

Comment: I see. Altough, my observation when testing was, that setting the view to nil and switching the rootViewController in the same event loop was actually causing the problem with the orientation not being propagated to the view controller. Setting the rootViewController in the window alone didn't cause any trouble. So maybe using `viewDidUnload` for memory handling and doing everything else in `viewWillAppear` is better?

Comment: @k: thanks again. Even when they don't occur in the same event loop (such as the memory warning) it's still an issue. I'm not sure even how to work around this, as it's not just a matter of the rotation events not being called -- even if I call them manually the screen doesn't actually rotate. I don't get how you're *supposed* to do this in iOS 5.

Comment: I'm looking at your issue again today, because I'd really like to figure out what's happening there (for my own projects as well). Question: Would it be ok to recreate the whole view controller or do you want to keep it and just recreate the view?

Comment: @k, it looks like changing `window.rootViewController = newController` to the two `removeFromSuperview`/`addSubview` lines fixed all my problems. Weird, and thank you very much!